# How to exlude empty fields in sendmail function (Google Docs script editor)

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am stuck with this last thing.

My script currently send an email to the admin (me) with all the fields entered in the Google form created taken from the spreadsheet associated.

Some field are not mandatory and therefore show up blank in the email.  If the field is is not filled out, I want to have it not seen in the email at all.

is this possible?

This is my current script

```
    var emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var body = "<HTML><BODY>"
    + "<P>" + "New Form submitted on: " + data[0][0]  // timestamp
      +  "<table id='vertical-1'>"
      +  "<table align='left'>"
      +  "</table>"
      +  "<font = 'Verdana'>"
      +  "<width = '600px'>"
      +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>CRC Representative:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][1] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
      +     "<tr>"
      +      "<th align='left'>Customer Name:</th>"
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][2] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
      +     "<tr>"
      +      "<th align='left'>Drivers Name:</th>"
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][3] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
      +     "<tr>"
      +      "<th align='left'>Address:</th>"
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][4] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
      +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Primary Phone:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][5] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
      +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Secondary Phone:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][6] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
      +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Email Address:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][7] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Year and Model:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][9] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>VIN:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][10] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Current Mileage:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][11] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Purchase Type:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][12] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Retail Dealer:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][13] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>New or Used:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][14] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Purchase Date:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][16] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Is it Certified/Select?:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][17] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>AMM:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][18] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Servicing Retailers:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][19] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>In service now?:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][20] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>What retailer and when did it arrive?:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][21] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Is the customer making an appointment?:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][22] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Why Not?:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][23] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
       +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>When:</th>"  // change
      +      "<td>"+ data[0][24] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
      +    "<tr>" 
      +      "<th align='left'>Brief Description of the issues and why the demand has been made:</th>"  // change
      +     "<td>"+ data[0][25] +"</td>"
      +     "</tr>"
      +   "</table>"
     + "</HTML></BODY>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find yourself repeating code, using cut & paste, pause and think about writing a function to do the job instead.

In this case, here's how we can spew out HTML for a table row only if it's non-blank:

```
function addRowIfData( heading, item ) {
  var rowHtml = '';
  if (item && item !== '') {
    rowHtml = "<tr>" 
          +      "<th align='left'>" + heading + "</th>"
          +      "<td>"+ data[0][1] +"</td>"
          +   "</tr>"
  }
  return rowHtml;
}
```

And this is what your original code collapses down to. I've left out many lines of the table, but you get the idea.

```
  var emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var body = "<HTML><BODY>"
          + "<P>" + "New Form submitted on: " + data[0][0]  // timestamp
          +  "<table id='vertical-1'>"
          +  "<table align='left'>"
          +  "</table>"
          +  "<font = 'Verdana'>"
          +  "<width = '600px'>"
          + addRowIfData('CRC Representative:', data[0][1]);
          + addRowIfData('Customer Name:', data[0][2]);
          + addRowIfData('Drivers Name:', data[0][3]);
          + addRowIfData('Address:', data[0][4]);
          + addRowIfData('Primary Phone:', data[0][5]);
          + addRowIfData('Secondary Phone:', data[0][6]);
          + addRowIfData('Email Address:', data[0][7]);
          + addRowIfData('Year and Model:', data[0][8]);
          // And So on...
          + addRowIfData('Brief Description of the issues and why the demand has been made:', data[0][25]);
          +   "</table>"
         + "</HTML></BODY>";
```

Now, if you put those headers into an array, you could change your code to:

```
...
for (row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
  addRowIfData(header[row],data[0][row]);
}
...
```